# Catalan Numbers vs Bell Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers, bell-numbers

I did a lot of research on Catalan Numbers and I came across one interesting fact that the nth Catalan numbers never exceeds the nth Bell number. I know that the nth bell numbers counts the number of partitions of a set with n elements.

My question is : Is there an easy way to prove that the nth Catalan number never exceeds the nth Bell number ? or is there an easy way to see it (with out even proof)

Comment: Both have a representation in terms of the factorial function.... perhaps Stirling's Approximation would help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the many things counted by the $n$th Catalan number is the number of [non-crossing partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition) of an ordered set of $n$ elements.

Since every non-crossing partition is, in particular, a partition, the number of non-crossing partitions cannot exceed the number of partitions, which is the $n$th Bell number.

---

More concretely, here is a way to encode a Dyck word of length $2n$ as a partition of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$:
Split the Dyck words up into $n$ groups of two symbols, and substitute each group as follows:
$$ \begin{align} \mathtt{((} &\mapsto \mathtt{[*} \\
\mathtt{))} &\mapsto \mathtt{*]} \\
\mathtt{()} &\mapsto \mathtt{[*]} \\
\mathtt{)(} &\mapsto \mathtt{*} \end{align} $$

The result of this substitution is a string with $n$ instances of $\mathtt{*}$ and some well-nested square brackets such that every $\mathtt{*}$ is inside at least one set of square brackets.

Each $\mathtt{*}$ represents one of the base element $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and there will be one set in the partition for each set of square brackets, containing exactly those stars that are within the brackets and *not* within any internal set of brackets. The rules guarantee that each of the sets is non-empty.

This representation is unique: If we're given a partition that comes from this process we can reconstruct the Dyck word it comes from uniquely: Go through the base set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ from left to right and follow these rules:

- If you're looking at the *only* element in some set, put down $\mathtt{()}$.
- If you're looking at the *smallest* element in some set, put down $\mathtt{((}$.
- If you're looking at the *largest* element in some set, put down $\mathtt{))}$.
- If you're looking at an element that is neither smallest nor largest in its set, put down $\mathtt{)(}$.

(A *non-crossing partition* of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is exactly one that can be produced by this construction.)

Comment: I actually read about that yes, But can you please give a simple definition and example of what it means to be a non-crossing partition, The wikipedia definition makes me confused

Comment: @alkabary: I've tried to edit with a more concrete description.

Comment: @alkabary: Imagine that $1,\ldots,n$ label the vertices of a regular $n$-gon in order, and you have a partition of those vertices. Let $P$ and $Q$ be two parts of the partition. The parts $P$ and $Q$ *cross* if there are $i,j\in P$ and $k,\ell\in Q$ such that the diagonals $ij$ and $k\ell$ intersect. A *crossing partition* of the vertices is one that has two parts that cross. Every other partition is a *non-crossing partition*.